# How to remove class on resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, I have a hamburger menu button that, when clicked, opens a `<ul>` but also changes the 3 lines to an X (with a JQuery toggle that activates a secondary set of CSS variables). When it is clicked again, the `<ul>` disappears and the X changes back to the original set of variables (the 3 lines). I have also set it so that if the page is resized when the list is open, the list closes and I'm trying to make it so that the resize changes the button changes back to the original set of CSS variables (i.e the lines).

Here is the JS and JQuery:

```
<script>
      window.onload = function(){
        document.querySelector('#menu-icon').addEventListener('click',function(){
          this.classList.toggle('active');
        });
        $(window).on('resize',function(){
             $("#menu-mobile").hide();

        });
      };
    </script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#menu-icon').click(function(){
        $("#menu-mobile").slideToggle("medium");     
      });
    </script>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#menu-icon {
    margin-top: 27px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #menu-icon > span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 6px;
    border-top: 3px solid #666;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(.15,1.43,.46,1.25);
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(.15,1.43,.46,1.25);
    margin: inherit auto;
  }
  #menu-icon:hover > span {
    border-top: 3px solid #333;
  }
  #menu-icon.active > .ln-one {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: top left;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #menu-icon.active > .ln-two {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  #menu-icon.active > .ln-three {
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(6px) translateX(-6px);
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(6px) translateX(-6px);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(6px) translateX(-6px);
  }
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the class on the resize event as well.

**jQuery**

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
     $("#menu-mobile").hide();
     $('#menu-icon').removeClass('active');
});
```

or via **classList API**

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
     $("#menu-mobile").hide();
     document.querySelector('#menu-icon').classList.remove('active');
});
```

Also it's better to place your `jquery.js` before all other `<script>` tags as it may produce some errors.

Comment: Awesome, thanks dude you're amazing! I'd upvote you but I don't have the required reputation.